Compatible function defining the equivalence relation $\sim$ such that $\oplus_i G_i/\sim$ is the limit of the directed system of abelian groups $G_i$
What I would like to know is the following: I have a direct limit constructed as a quotient of the subgroup $\oplus_i G_i$ of $\prod_i G_i$ denoted by $\varinjlim_{i\in I}G_i=\oplus_i G_i/\sim$ where $\sim$ denotes an equivalence relation on $\oplus_i G_i$. How would I define a corresponding compatible function. Specifically, can the definition be described without reference to any category theory language? I know that direct and inverse limits have to do with limit and co-limit in category theory. I am still not very used to category theory concepts and am not very confident and really try to understand it at the level of undergraduate abstract algebra.  Rosenberg's text is the only other place where I can find a definition of direct limit of stuff that talks about how himomorphic maps  are "compatible" to another map which I am not sure if it agrees with the one used in Velleman's text.
Background:
The following is taken from:

A Graduate Course In Algebra - Volume 1 by Ioannis Farmakis and Martin Moskowitz,
How to Prove it by Dan Velleman, and
An Invitation to Abstract Algebra by Steven J. Rosenberg.

[From Velleman's How to Prove it, 2nd edition]
Suppose $f:A\to B$ and $R$ is an equivalence relation on $A$, We will say that $f$ is compatible with $R$ if $\forall x\in A\forall y\in A(xRy\to f(x)=f(y))$.
[From Farmakis and Moskowitz's text]
Definition 1:  Let $(I, \preceq)$ be a partially ordered set with the property that for any two elements $i,j$ there is some $k\in I$ such that $i\preceq k, j\preceq k$. A directed system of sets (groups, rings, modules, topological spaces, etc.) indexed by $I$ is a collection of sets (rrespectively groups, rings, modules, topological spaces, etc.)  $X_i, i\in I)$, and maps (respectively homomorphisms, contiuous maps, etc.)  $f_{ij}:X_i\to X_j$, defined whenever $i\preceq j$, satisfies the following compatibility conditions:

$f_{ik}=f_{jk}\circ f_{ij}, i\preceq j \preceq k$, and
$f_{ii}=\mathrm{Id}_{X_i}$.

A direct (or inductive) limit of the directed system of groups $G_i$, is defined by giving a group $G$ and a homomorphism
$$\phi_i:G_i\to G$$
for any $i\in I$ such that

if $i<j$ then $\phi_i=\phi_j\circ \phi_{ij}$,

[Note: the correct partial order should be $i\preceq j$, and $\phi_{ij}$ should be $f_{ij}$.]

if $(G',\phi'_i)$ is another group and family of homormophisms with the same property then there exists a unique homomorphism
$$\phi: G\to G'$$
such that $\phi_i=\phi\circ \phi'_i$ for any $i\in I$.

[Note:  the correct compositional map should be:  $\phi^{'}_i=\phi\circ \phi_i$.  Also, if it will make things easiser, the groups can be assumed to be abelian.]
The direct limit can be constructed as the quotient of the subgroup $\oplus_i G_i$ of $\prod_i G_i$ as follows:  $$\varinjlim_{i\in I}G_i=\oplus_i G_i/\sim$$
where, $x_i\in G_i$ is equivalent to $x_j\in G_j$ if and only if
$$\phi_{ik}(x_i)=\phi_{jk}(x_j)$$
for some $k\in I,$ with the additional structure that the product of $x_i\in G_i, x_j\in G_j$ is defined as the product of their images in $G_k$.
[From Rosenberg's text]
Definition 2:
Let $I$ be a partially ordered set such that every pair $\{i,j\}\subset I$ has an upper bound in $I$, and let $\{R_i\}_{i\in I}$ be a collection of rings indexed by $I$.  Suppose that whenever $i,j\in I$ with $i\leq j$, we have a ring homomorphism $\sigma_{i,j}:R_i\to R_j$, and that they homomorphisms are compatible in the sense that whenever $i\leq j\leq k$ we have $\sigma_{j,k}\circ\sigma_{i,j}=\sigma_{i,k}$.  Then a direct lmit of the rings $R_i$ with respect to the maps $\sigma_{i,j}$ is a ring $R$ together with ring homomorphism $e_i:R_i\to R$ such that for every ring $T$ with ring homomorphism $\tau_i: R_i\to T$ compatible with the maps $\sigma_{i,j}$, there exists a ring homorophism $\omega:R\to T$ making the following diagram commute:
$\quad\quad (*)$
Note:  when we say that the $\tau_i$ are compatible with the $\sigma_{i,j}$, we mean that the outer triangle in $(*)$ commutes.

There seems to be something missing in your Definition 2. What concept is it intended to be a definition of? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_set, I guess.

@AnneBauval I edited my post to added screenshots from the texts for definitions 2,3, and 4.  For Definition 5, I typed the text verbatium.  I hope this make the post more clear.

Please do not rely on pictures of text.

Hi Seth, thanks for the screenshots! They clarify your synthesis of these texts. I renumbered your definitions accordingly since, as suspected, your "Definition 2" wasn't a definition but an introduction to the definition which followed that sentence. However, I think your post would be easier to read if you shorten it by removing everything after Definitions 2 and 3 (no more screenshots, no Dummit and Foote, and no table).

@AnneBauval other than removing those Definitions, table sign posts, etc.  What I am trying to ask is clear?

Yes it is clear. You could even remove most of Velleman's exercises, if not all.

@AnneBauval I edited it according to your suggestions.  Also, thank you for the editing suggestions.

@Shaun I only included the screenshots to give clarification to what Anne Bauval was asking.  I just want to make sure nothing in what I wrote cause any difficulties for the reader to understand.

Let $(I,\preceq)$ be a directed set and $(G_i)_{i\in I},(\phi_{ij})_{i\preceq j}$ a direct system of abelian groups (noted additively).
The direct sum $\bigoplus_i G_i$ is defined as the subgroup of $\prod_iG_i$ consisting of families $g=(g_i)_i\in\prod_iG_i$ such that for some finite subset $J\subset I$: $\forall i\in I\setminus J\quad g_i=0_i$ (the identity element of $G_i$).
Let $H$ be the subgroup of such $g$s for which moreover, for some $k\succeq J$, $\sum_{i\in J}\phi_{ik}(g_i)=0_k$.
Farmakis and Moskowitz's (admittedly sloppy) definition of the equivalence relation $\sim$ on $\bigoplus_i G_i$ intends to mean that
$g\sim h$ iff $g-h\in H$.
You can check that the quotient group $G:={\left(\bigoplus_i G_i\right)/\sim}={\left(\bigoplus_i G_i\right)/H}$, together with the natural homomorphisms $G_i\to G$, satisfies the conditions to embody 'the' direct limit $\varinjlim_{i\in I}G_i$.
That was the main point to understand. After that, defining a 'corresponding compatible function' $f$ is easy but not enlightening: you can consider e.g. the canonical homomorphism from $\bigoplus_i G_i$ onto the quotient group $G$. This 'compatibility' in the sense of Velleman's definition should not be confused with Rosenberg's 'compatibility' of his maps $\tau_i$, which simply means $\tau_i=\tau_j\circ\sigma_{ij}$ (Velleman only alludes to it when writing 'family of homormophisms with the same property', meaning: $\phi'_i=\phi'_j\circ f_{ij}$). Note also that Rosenberg forgot to require the similar 'compatibility' of his maps $e_i$.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

@AnneBauval Sorry for my late reply.  I emailed one of the authors (Martin Moskowitz) on May 23rd in regards to your italized comment.  I still has not gotten a response.  He is retired and his co-author has passed away.  Thank you again for trying to clarify the comment.   For the record, the statement that is copied from the book you referenced to is:  '"An important caveat: the direct limit of a family of abelian groups in the category of abelian groups is different from the direct limit in the category of all groups!...

@AnneBauval .... This is connected to the fact that the coproduct in the category
of abelian groups is the direct sum."'

Indeed, whence my comment (after reading carefully Gouvea), explaining his mistake (reproduced by Farmakis&Moskowitz): 1, 2. In short: for directed limits, the coproduct is off topic.

@AnneBauval can you write to Gouvea to let him know of the error. I don't have the mathematical credibility nor the technical competence to tell him there is an error in those passages. I think since the book is meant for beginners, and the book serves as a general tour guide for abstract algebra of a sort. I think if you write to him to let him know, he would appreciate it. He is still active in the math book writing scene.
